# AngularJS, pagination for images from flickr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am creating an app that should fetch images from flickr and show 20 of them on each page. Now, there are many custom directives out there for pagination of text data from JSON, but I've no idea how to make it work with images. I've tried with dirPagination.js which is kinda popular, but I couldn't make it to work. Ill provide the code, and kindly ask for help with this one.
HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="recentImages">
<div ng-repeat="item in imageList.photos.photo">
    <div id="imgThumbs">
        <img src="https://farm{{item.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{item.server}}/{{item.id}}_{{item.secret}}_m.jpg" alt=""/>    
    </div>      
</div>                                      
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);


 var recent = "flickr.photos.getRecent";
var page = 1;

App.controller('recentImages', ['$scope', 'forAllone', function($scope, forAllone) {
    forAllone.success(function(data) {
    $scope.imageList = data;
  });
}]);



App.factory('forAllone', ['$http', function($http) { 
        return $http.get('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&format=json&nojsoncallback=?&per_page=20&page='+page+'&api_key=5eb283c54e823624591d2c22db0217cb') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my solution below.

You need to add in some controls to paginate back and forward and bind there click event to increment/decrement from your page variable. I altered your factory a bit so we can call the image retriever with a parameter. I pu the page variable into the controller scope so we could access it within our dom easier, and use that to turn our previous controls on or off.

These photos are coming in fast, so the view doens't change a whole lot sometimes, but this does what you're looking for:

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);

var recent = "flickr.photos.getRecent";

App.controller('recentImages', ['$scope', 'forAllone', function($scope, forAllone) {

  $scope.page = 0;
 $scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.page += 1;
    $scope.getPage()
  }
 $scope.prevPage = function() {
    $scope.page -= 1;
    $scope.getPage()
  }
  $scope.getPage = function() {
    $scope.imageList = [];
    forAllone.getPage($scope.page).success(function(data) {
      $scope.imageList = data;
    });
  }
}]).factory('forAllone', ['$http', function($http) {

  var factory = {};

  factory.getPage = function(page) {

    return $http.get('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&format=json&nojsoncallback=?&per_page=20&page=' + page + '&api_key=5eb283c54e823624591d2c22db0217cb')
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        return err;
      });
  }
  return factory;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="recentImages" ng-init="getPage()">
    page: {{page}}
    <a ng-click="nextPage()" href="#next">next</a>
    <a ng-click="prevPage()" ng-if="page > 0" href="#prev">previous</a>
    <div ng-repeat="item in imageList.photos.photo">
      <div id="imgThumbs">
        <img ng-src="https://farm{{item.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{item.server}}/{{item.id}}_{{item.secret}}_m.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Jesus, this was awesome, quick and accurate answer. Thanks a bunch Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-src`, `img src...` does not allow dynamic data.
It clearly says in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc